# How to create a GUESS the number game(machine guesses the number the user is thinking)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script to guess the number by the user starting from 0.For some reason my code it's no working the way i wanted:

```
import random
choice = "WRONG"
comp = random.randint(0,100)
while choice !="EQUAL":
  choice = input("Is the number bigger or equal or smaller a " + str(comp) + "?\n").upper
  if choice=="EQUAL":
    print('machine wins')
  elif choice=="SMALLER":
    comp = random.randint(0,comp)
  elif choice =="BIGGER":
    comp =random.randint(comp,100)
```

Comment: you just forgot the `()` after `upper`. Now you should improve your script to not forget the previous inputs. When I say "bigger than 75", then "smaller than 90", the computer shouldn't guess 10, but something between 75 and 90.

Comment: Thank you Dr.V.You got me curious.How could i make the program guess something between 75 and 90 in the example you said?

Comment: Have variables for upper and lower bound, starting with 0 and 100. Then change the bounds depending on what the user answers, before generating the next guess.